# How to use java-style iterators instead stl-style in the Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, iterator, qtcore, qmap

For example :

```
QList<QMap<QString,QString> > list

QList<QMap<QString,QString> >::iterator i;
    for (i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i)
    {
        QMap<QString,QString>::iterator j;
        for (j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j)
            qDebug() << j.key() << ": " << j.value() << endl;
    }
```

So this stl-style is working. But i can't rewrite to java-style :

```
   QListIterator<QMap<QString,QString> > i(list);
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        QMapIterator<QString,QString> j(i); //error 
        while (j.hasNext()) {
            j.next();
            qDebug() << j.key() << ": " << j.value() << endl;
        }
    }
```

Here i get error - `cannot convert parameter 1 from QListIterator<T>' to 'const QMap<Key,T>`

Comment: Did my answer resolve the issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the next item when using a java style iterator as follows:

```
 QMapIterator<QString,QString> j(i.next()); //no error
```